# How to use multiprocess in another code and funcion?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess cell detection via the deepcell package. Because the deepcell detection works fine on small images. But for bigger images it does not work or takes a really really long time.
So I'm trying to cut the images into small patches, and then use multiprocessing to feed them to the cell detection.
I need to be able to run the pool_cell_detection() function in another code, and get its return value (allPoints). Whereas if I use it in a if **name**=='**main**' wrapper, then I could not get the return value. Can you suggest how I can do this?

Here is my code1

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv
from multiprocessing import Pool
from deepcell.mesmer import Mesmer
import time

blevel_image = cv.imread("./images/blevel_eq_p.png",0)
app = Mesmer()


def deepcell_detection(image0, mpp):
    print(type(image0))
    cv.imwrite("./images/image1.png", image0)
    image = np.stack((image0,image0), axis=-1)
    image = np.expand_dims(image,0)
    labeled_image, coords = app.predict(image, image_mpp=mpp)
    print(len(coords))
    return coords

def pool_cell_detection(img_channel):
    blobs_log = []
    r,c = img_channel.shape[0:2]
    mpp = 2
    rstep=r//10
    cstep=c//10
    patches=[]
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            img_patch = img_channel[i*rstep:(i+1)*rstep,j*cstep:(j+1)*cstep]
            patches.append([img_patch, mpp])
    with Pool(4) as p:
        print("pooling")
        allPoints=p.map(deepcell_detection, patches)
    return allPoints

def main():
    allPoints = pool_cell_detection(blevel_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I need in code 2 something like the following:

```
import code1

def func_something():
    #Many operations
    allPoints = pool_cell_detection(blevel_image)
```

But I'm not sure how to write code 2 to be able to get the allpoints

Comment: Well, I would say the error message is pretty self-explanatory (tip: `This probably means that you [...] have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module.`).

Comment: @MaryamSadeghi With your last edit, you still don't have a `__name__ == '__main__'` guard, you have `name == '__main__'` (which will cause a NameError); you're also now calling `pool_cfos_detection` (which doesn't exist). Please show us the actual code you've tried to run, and the actual error you're getting.

Comment: I'm sorry, a lot of errors there, I was just quickly trying to get my point accross. I need to output the allpoints value in another code. That is why I don't know how to go about that, while using the __main__ guard

Comment: What do you mean with "in another code"? So long as whatever code ends up calling a function that uses `multiprocessing` has been started from a module with the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard, you're fine.

Comment: So for example in the above, I have named them code1 and code2. Should I use if __name__ == "__main__" in code 2, and not code1?

Comment: If you start your program with e.g. `python code2.py`, then yes, that file must have the guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As the `multiprocessing` documentation says, the entry point of a `multiprocessing` program *must* be wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__':` when using the `spawn` start method, which is the only available option on Windows, which you're on.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)

Change the final invocation from

```
blobs_log = pool_cell_detection(blevel_image)
```

to e.g.

```
def main():
    blobs_log = pool_cell_detection(blevel_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Following up on the comment threads, all in all, you might have, let's say, `multiprocessing_cell_detect.py`:

```
import multiprocessing

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from deepcell.mesmer import Mesmer


def deepcell_detection(image0, mpp):
    cv.imwrite("./images/image1.png", image0)
    image = np.stack((image0, image0), axis=-1)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    labeled_image, coords = Mesmer().predict(image, image_mpp=mpp)
    return coords


def pool_cell_detection(img_channel):
    r, c = img_channel.shape[0:2]
    mpp = 2
    rstep = r // 10
    cstep = c // 10
    patches = []
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            img_patch = img_channel[i * rstep:(i + 1) * rstep, j * cstep:(j + 1) * cstep]
            patches.append([img_patch, mpp])
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
        return p.map(deepcell_detection, patches)
```

and `my_cell_program.py`:

```
from multiprocessing_cell_detect import pool_cell_detection

def main():
    blevel_image = cv.imread("./images/blevel_eq_p.png", 0)
    allPoints = pool_cell_detection(blevel_image)
    print(allPoints)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and you run `python my_cell_program.py`.

So long as the main entry point of the program is guarded, things will work. The module you import a multiprocessing thing from will not need to be guarded (unless you *also* wish to use that module stand-alone).

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to run the code as __main__. this will be in a function that will be called from a different file. Would that not be possible?

Comment: Well, yes, it would, but that entry point must be similarly guarded, then.

Comment: Sorry could you please explain me what you mean by guarded?

Comment: That the program's main entry point must have that `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard explained above.

Comment: I edited my question to show why I have a problem with using this guard. Would you mind reading it again?

Comment: @MaryamSadeghi Your edited code doesn't show you using the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard (or in fact calling the `pool_cell_detection` function at all).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247648/discussion-between-maryam-sadeghi-and-akx).

Comment: @MaryamSadeghi Did you get things to work in the end? If you did, please remember to mark the answer as accepted...